# Can I access a database while TDE is being enabled?

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

I have a question regarding Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) on a large database. While TDE is being enabled on the database, can I continue to access it? Specifically, can I perform SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE operations on the database?

I understand that TDE encrypts data at rest, but I'm not sure if that affects the ability to access the data while the encryption process is taking place. I would greatly appreciate any insight or advice from those who have experience with TDE.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> While TDE is being enabled on the database, can I continue to access it? Specifically, can I perform SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE operations on the database?

Yes, you can, however TDE may cause blocking if it's working on specific pages for those objects. It won't stay that way for long, once the encryption is finished it will be written back to disk as encrypted and move on, however if many of those extents for the object exist in a contiguous fashion on disk and you're running a DML query which looks at a range or large amount of data, this can look like continuous blocking (though it should still be making headway, just slowly or however fast your cpu/memory/disk system can allow).

Note that, depending on the SQL Server version, you can create a resource group to manage the resource usage. If it's a large database, you don't want to do this as you want the encryption scan to complete as fast as possible.

Also note, depending on the SQL Server version you can pause and resume the encryption scan if it's giving you too much performance trouble, such as pausing it during high traffic and resuming overnight, then pausing again in the morning.